# VBA Decimal issue after replacing a hyphen with dot

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub BatchCopyTextNewColumn()

    Dim LastRow As Integer

'Variables declared as per Solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967189    /vba-'decimal-issue-after-replacing-a-hyphen-with-dot
'by Jagadish Dabbiru (July 25, 2014)

    Dim i As Integer

    Dim BatchNo() As String
    Dim ArrBatchNo As Long

    Worksheets("DataFile").Activate

    Cells(1, 17).Select

'Rename Columns

    Cells(1, 17).Value = "BatchNumeric"

    Cells(1, 18).Select

'Rename Columns

    Cells(1, 18).Value = "BatchCheck_Old_New"

'Ask user to provide you with the Batch# from the last data set e.g. which was received a week ago.

'Last Row is defined by the Column 1 "AccountString"

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With Range("O2", Range("O1").End(xlDown))

        .Copy

    End With

'Use the PasteSpecial method:

    Range("Q2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967189/vba-decimal-issue-after-'replacing-a-hyphen-with-dot
'by Jagadish Dabbiru (July 25, 2014)
'Take each value from column q and Split the batch code with delimiter hyphen(-).
'Then check the length of the value of 2nd array element.
'If length is 1 digit then add 0 as prefix else keep as it is.

    i = 1
    Do
    BatchNo = Worksheets("DataFile").Range("Q" & i).Value
    ArrBatchNo = Split(BatchNo, "-")
    If Len(ArrBatchNo(1)) = 1 Then
    ArrBatchNo = "0" & ArrBatchNo
    End If
    Worksheets("DataFile").Range("Q" & i).Value = ArrBatchNo(0) & "." & ArrBatchNo(1)
    i = i + 1
    Loop While Worksheets("DataFile").Range("Q" & i).Value <> ""

    Range("Q2").Activate

End Sub
```

There is a problem with decimals after replacing hyphens with dots.

Originally the Batch numbers are issued with hyphens. I need to use them as values as I have to distinguish between "OLD" Batch numbers (sent previously) and "NEW" (larger than the last Batch number).

Hyphen replacement (my code):

```
Sub ReplaceBatchCharacter()

Range("Q2").Activate

Worksheets("DataFile").Columns("Q").Replace _
'I tried to replace it with "." and there is a problem with decimals as well (e.g. batch # 4230-1 and 4230-10 are both shown as 4210.10 after replacement
    What:="-", Replacement:=".0", _

'by replacing with ".0" I have solution for batch #'s xxxx-1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9 but when it starts with double digits xxxx-10 etc I have similar problem as they become xxxx.010 etc.
So the batch number 4230-1 and 4230-10 are both shown as 4210.010 after replacement.
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

End Sub

Check Old and New Batch # (my code):

Sub BatchNumberCheckNewOld()

Dim BatchNumberPrevious As Single
Dim BatchNumberCurrentCell As Range
Dim BatchNumberCurrentRange As Range
Dim BatchNumberCurrentResult As String
Dim LastRow As Long
'Dim ChangedRange As Range

Worksheets("DataFile").Activate

Range("Q2").Activate

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).Row

'Ask user to provide us with the Batch# from the last data set e.g. which was received a week ago.

'Last Row is defined by the Column 1 "AccountString"

'BatchNumberPrevious = 4250.1

BatchNumberPrevious = InputBox("Please enter the last Batch # from previous period. Don't forget to reconcile TB's (prior and current months). Ocassionally OLD batches could be NEW.")

Set BatchNumberCurrentRange = Range(Cells(2, 17), Cells(LastRow, 17))

For Each BatchNumberCurrentCell In BatchNumberCurrentRange

If BatchNumberPrevious >= BatchNumberCurrentCell.Value Then

    BatchNumberCurrentResult = "Old"

Else

    BatchNumberCurrentResult = "New"

End If

'BatchNumberCurrentResult column should be populated by offsetting BatchNumberCurrentCell variable

BatchNumberCurrentCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = BatchNumberCurrentResult

Next BatchNumberCurrentCell

'Autofit width of columns

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that the "OLD" and "NEW" batch numbers are not identified correctly because numbers are having issue with decimals:

Comment: 'I tried to replace it with "." and there is a problem with decimals as well (e.g. batch # 4230-1 and 4230-10 are both shown as 4210.10 after replacement
    What:="-", Replacement:=".0", _

'by replacing with ".0" I have solution for batch #'s xxxx-1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9 but when it starts with double digits xxxx-10 etc I have similar problem as they become xxxx.010 etc.
So the batch number 4230-1 and 4230-10 are both shown as 4210.010 after replacement.

Comment: BatchNumeric BatchCheck_Old_New
4462.1 New
4452.5 New
4438.1 Old
4438.2 Old
4438.3 Old
4438.4 Old
4438.5 Old
4438.6 New
4438.7 New
4438.8 New
4438.9 New
4438.1 Old
4438.11 Old
4438.12 Old
4438.13 Old
4438.14 Old
4438.15 Old
4438.16 Old
4438.17 Old

Comment: I tested batch number 4438-5 (before hyphen was replaced). This batch number became 4438.5 after replacement with "."

Comment: It works OK for 4438.9 and smaller but it is not working for 4438.10 and larger. How can I fix it? Will conditional replacement help (e.g. replace for "-10" and higher with "." and for 1 to 9 with ".0")? I just don't know how to write a code for it...

Comment: test results for ".0" (batch number is the same 4438.05 after adding 0):

Comment: BatchNumeric BatchCheck_Old_New
4462.01 New
4452.05 New
4438.01 Old
4438.02 Old
4438.03 Old
4438.04 Old
4438.05 Old
4438.06 New
4438.07 New
4438.08 New
4438.09 New
4438.01 Old
4438.011 Old
4438.012 Old
4438.013 Old
4438.014 Old
4438.015 Old
4438.016 Old
4438.017 Old
4441.01 New
4441.02 New
4441.03 New
4441.04 New
4441.05 New
4441.06 New
4441.07 New
4441.08 New
4441.09 New
4441.01 New
4441.011 New
4441.012 New

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take each value from column q and Split the batch code with delimiter hyphen(-). Then check the length of the value of 2nd array element. If length is 1 digit then add 0 as prefix  else keep as it is.

```
i =1
Do 
BatchNo = Worksheets("DataFile").Range("Q"& i).Value 
ArrBatchNo = Split(BatchNo,"-")
If Len(ArrBatchNo(1)) = 1 Then
ArrBatchNo(1) = "0" & ArrBatchNo (1)
End If
Worksheets("DataFile").Range("Q"& i).Value = ArrBatchNo(0) & "." & ArrBatchNo(1)
i = i+1
Loop While Worksheets("DataFile").Range("Q"& i).Value <> ""
```

Comment: Hi Jagadish,
Thank you very much for your prompt and explicit solution.
Arrays are new to me. I have declared variables but there is a Compile error: type mismatch  with regards to BatchNo. 
Here is a code.
Could you take a look and tell me what is wrong?
Thank you, 
Russ1969

Comment: I have edited my original post by adding a new Sub BatchCopyTextNewColumn. Chronologically it should go before replacing hyphen with dot.Thank you

Comment: Thank you, Jagadish. Anyway when I changed it to Dim ArrBatchNo As Array it gives me the following error: "Compile error: Expected New or  type name...

Comment: after ReplaceBatchCharacter() function you forgot to comment this line 'Check Old and New Batch # (my code):

Comment: In Dim BatchNo() as String remove (). It should be BatchNo as String

Comment: Thank you.I have a line "Check Old and New Batch # (my code):" in stachoverflow screen only, it is not in my final code,so nothing to fix here. As per your advice, I have changed variable declaration for array, now it is Dim BatchNo as String. The same error occurs: ""Compile error: Expected New or type name". I am new to this Forum and I am not sure what would be the most effective and efficient way to continue this discussion. Should we move to chat or it is OK to continue here? Thank you,Russ

Comment: ArrBatchNo as Array is not accepted (should it be as Variant?) Would you recommend to use ReDim ArrBatchNo(1) as there could be only 2 arguments (either single number (1-9) or double (10-99). If I make the changes mentioned above, I still have data mismatch error on line: ArrBatchNo = "0" & ArrBatchNo. Also I changed i=2 because data starts on row 2 (row 1 is a heading).I am stuck... There are a lot topics related to data mismatch and split function.

Comment: First of all. Remove option explicit and remove all the 'Dim' declarations and try to run. As this is not the recommended way of coding but you need to do this to ensure where exactly your code is failing. If code works then there is a problem in declarations otherwise some other issue.  Learn debugging techniques from google.

Comment: Some modification for my  code i have done according to your error in 6th line. Check it out

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice and modification of line 6. A missing argument (1) was a final piece to solve this puzzle. Results after testing (last batch 4438.01) = 4438.01 (old) and 4438.10 (new). 0 was added before 1-length item only. I really appreciate your great and prompt help. As I mentioned before, I am new to this helpful forum, could you tell me how to close the case (just accept answer? - already done) and how to give you well-deserved credits? Thank you, Russ

Comment: Unfortunately I am not entitled to vote up util I pass threshold of 15 reputation points. Anyway it does not reduce the importance and efficiency of your work!!! Thank you again!!!